# What do you call the oral accounts that you give to a detective?

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought the word was *testimony*. But then discovered that it's usually used to describe what you say in court:

> [testimony](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=testimony%20define&oq=testimony%20define&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l9.7732.8364.0.8540.7.6.0.0.0.0.154.421.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..4.3.419.4oYcaZGokl4) 
>   a formal written or spoken statement, especially one given in a court
>   of law.

What to call the accounts/answer that you give to a detective during a questioning session?

Example sentence:

> Miss Anderson seems to be telling the truth. It fits her previous [...].

Comment: A *statement*? Eg witness statement

Comment: The word *testimony* is less used in the UK. We talk about *giving evidence* - to a police officer, later in court. I believe a *statement* to be the written-down evidence which the witness signs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a **statement**.

Police interview/question suspects, witnesses, and "persons of interest" (possible suspects?) .  All of them give **statements**.

It's not *testimony* unless it's given in court or in a *deposition*  (AmE)

http://www.google.com/search?q=deposition+definition+law

Comment: In Britain a *statement* is a written account, usually taken down by a police officer from the witness' verbal remarks, and which the witness signs. Nowadays there are strict rules concerning the taking of statements, including an audio recording.

Comment: You can talk to a police officer and answer questions quite informally, and there's no particular word for this. If it's to be used in evidence, what you say has to be recorded and authenticated according to strict guidelines (as WS2 describes), and then it does constitute a *statement*.

Comment: In actual practice, they don't follow the guidelines at all. They record your conversation, then edit it as it pleases them, leak out-of-context excerpts to the press, and never make a transcript.  That's why (advice I failed to take) NEVER answer any police questions without a lawyer present.